# momentjs format time in seperate hours an minutes

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I use momentjs inside angular js and I acount the duration in seconds and I can format it in `HH:mm` format as `03:35` but I cannot find in documentaion and google to how show it in format `3h 35m` could anybody point me to right documentation???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get what you're after:

```
moment().format("H[h] mm[m]");
```

Take a look at [Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) from the momement.js docs. The `[]` is used to escape characters in format strings.

Comment: `@John Veldboom` thanks a lot I don't know why I didn't realize that