# moment js function to show duration in human readable format like (5 hours and 10 minutes) from number of seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Is there any function available in `moment.js` to convert seconds into human readable duration like for `3720` seconds it should show `1 Hours and 2 minutes`.

I know this can be easily done with simple math operations like `%` and `/`, but i am searching if any `moment.js` function available for it.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [momentjs format time in seperate hours an minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596884/momentjs-format-time-in-seperate-hours-an-minutes)

Comment: @Martijn, This is not what i need i know fromnow function but i want to convert seconds into hours and minutes. And i have only seconds in value not any timestamp.

Comment: @derpirscher. No it dosen't help.. It shows `05` for `moment(3600).format('HH')`

Comment: @VinitSingh that's because `moment(3600)` is a timestamp at 1970-01-01T00:00:03.600 UTC, ie 3600 ms after the 1st of January 1970 (UTC). You are probably in a timezone UTC+5 and `HH` displays the local time ... Thus, the formatting works as expected, but you are generating the wrong moment ...

Comment: `console.log(moment.utc(3720000).format("H [Hours] m [Minutes] "))`  But all in all, the developers of momentjs consider it deprecated, thus it should not be used in new projects anymore ...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying [moment duration format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format), this gives you a lot of options:

```js
console.log("Duration (123 sec):", moment.duration(123, "seconds").format("mm:ss"));

console.log("Duration (350 sec):", moment.duration(350, "seconds").format("m [minutes] [and] s [seconds]"));
 
console.log("Duration (3720 seconds):", moment.duration(3720, "seconds").format("h [hours] [and] m [minutes]"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.js"></script>
```

I'd also consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html), this will give you the ability to format dates too:

```js
const { Duration } = luxon;

console.log(Duration.fromObject({ seconds: 3720 }).toFormat("h 'hours and' m 'minutes'"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-OyrI249ZRX2hY/1CAD+edQR90flhuXqYqjNYFJAiflsKsMxpUYg5kbDDAVA8Vp0HMlPG/aAl1tFASi1h4eRoQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As others have noted, moment.js is in maintenance mode (see [project-status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)), so you might consider using luxon instead (or another library)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Duration } = luxon;

console.log(Duration.fromObject({ seconds: 37200 }).toFormat("h 'hours and' m 'minutes'"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-OyrI249ZRX2hY/1CAD+edQR90flhuXqYqjNYFJAiflsKsMxpUYg5kbDDAVA8Vp0HMlPG/aAl1tFASi1h4eRoQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

c